# Assigning Pointers, Address operators and dereferencing pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

could you explain the following code,

```
int main() {
    int value = 2;
    int *ptrWithAmpersand = &value;
    int *ptrWithoutAmpersand = value;
    //printf("%d", *ptrWithoutAmpersand); 1) Why Runtime error.
    printf("Pointer with & --> %d\n", *ptrWithAmpersand);
    printf("Pointer withOUT & and * --> %d\n", ptrWithoutAmpersand); //2) Why this works??!!
    getch();
}
```

As commented in the code

1. Why Runtime Error?
2. Why this works?

Output is

```
Pointer with & --> 2
Pointer withOUT & and * --> 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
int *ptrWithAmpersand = &value;
```

you are creating a pointer to `int` and assigning the *address* of the variable `value` to it.  So far so good.

In the line

```
int *ptrWithoutAmpersand = value;
```

you are creating a pointer to `int` and assigning the *contents* of the variable `value` (2) to it.  This leads to several problems:

1. You are attempting to assign a value of type `int` to a variable of type `int *`, which are not compatible types; the compiler should at least issue a warning of "incompatible types in assignment" or something like that (turn on *all* warnings)
2. On your system, `2` is not a valid object address, hence the runtime error when you try to *dereference* `ptrWithoutAmpersand`.

You have several other problems in your code.  You should not use the `%d` conversion specifier to print out pointer values; always use `%p` for that purpose.

Here's a slight rewrite of your code to makes some things a little clearer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int value = 2;
    int *ptrWithAmpersand = &value;
    int *ptrWithoutAmpersand = value; // throws a warning in gcc; you should not do this

    printf("value of expression \"value\" = %d\n", value );
    printf("value of expression \"&value\" = %p\n", (void *) &value );
    printf("value of expression \"ptrWithAmpersand\" = %p\n", (void *) ptrWithAmpersand );
    printf("value of expression \"*ptrWithAmpersand\" = %d\n", *ptrWithAmpersand );
    printf("value of expression \"ptrWithoutAmpersand\" = %p\n", (void *) ptrWithoutAmpersand );

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output of the code:

```
value of expression "value" = 2
value of expression "&value" = 0x7ffecb63cf44
value of expression "ptrWithAmpersand" = 0x7ffecb63cf44
value of expression "*ptrWithAmpersand" = 2
value of expression "ptrWithoutAmpersand" = 0x2
```

Note how the pointer expression are printed out vs. the integer expressions.

In short:

```
*ptrWithAmpersand    ==  value == 2        type == int
 ptrWithAmpersand    == &value             type == int *
 ptrWithoutAmpersand ==  value == 2        mismatched types int * and int
```

Comment: That was a very detailed explanation. Helped me out alot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
int *ptrWithAmpersand = &value;
printf("Pointer with & --> %d\n", *ptrWithAmpersand);
```

you correctly assign an address to the pointer and in the `printf` you correctly dereference it to print an int with the `%d` parameter.

In:

```
int *ptrWithoutAmpersand = value;
printf("Pointer withOUT & and * --> %d\n", ptrWithoutAmpersand);
```

You are incorectly assigning an integer value to a pointer, but because in the `printf` you do not dereference it, it will be printed as an `int` with the `%d` parameter. This will only cause a problem (UB) if `sizeof(int *) != sizeof(int)`.

In:

```
int *ptrWithoutAmpersand = value;
printf("%d", *ptrWithoutAmpersand);
```

you get a runtime error because you are dereferencing a pointer that points to memory address `2`, which is not yours and so the system aborts your program.